# How to make word cloud for each cluster in kmeans

Tags: python, machine-learning, data-science, k-means, word-cloud

"I trying to print data points in each cluster using word cloud and my data points is vectorizer data(BOW),How to print words in each cluster using word cloud..?"

I already done optimal k for k-means after that i'm not getting any idea how to print words in each cluster

kmeanModel_bow = KMeans(n_clusters=2)

Can anyone help me on this how to  print words for each cluster using word cloud

Answer (score 1):

It won't be feasible to plot each word for each data point in your cluster. BOW will create thousands of features for each sentence. Even if you have only let's say 1000 data points(1 data point being one sentence) it will lead to plotting roughly lakhs of words for a single cluster. I would suggest plotting the cluster centre for each cluster.

To get the features of cluster centres:

> Use the [cluster_centers_](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cluster.KMeans.html#sklearn.cluster.KMeans.predict) attribute of KMeans function which returns NumPy Array.
> Each row will have feature corresponding to each cluster centre.
> Use the following code to get the feature words:

```
Words = np.array_str((np.take(vectorizer.get_feature_names(), featurearray)))
```

> You can then plot the obtained words using wordcloud.

Answer (score 0):

```
from wordcloud import WordCloud, STOPWORDS 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
import pandas as pd 

for tag  in  y_kmeans.labels_ :
if tag==1:
  tags1=element+" "+element[tag]
if tag==2:
  tags2=element+" "+element[tag]
if tag==3:
  tags3=element+" "+element[tag]

  wordcloud = WordCloud(width = 1000, height = 1000, 
            background_color ='white', 
            min_font_size = 14).generate(tag1) 

        plt.figure(figsize = (10, 10), facecolor = None) 
        plt.imshow(wordcloud)
```

Answer (score 0):

Found a better working approach to the problem. Centroid approach might not work because there is a high chance that the centroid BOW doesn't exist. Since the feature values would be calculated by taking the mean of other data points. You can use below logic to get words in a different cluster.

```
for i in tqdm(range(0,len(K_Means.labels_))):


   lisst = BOWVectorDataPoint[i].nonzero()

   if   K_Means.labels_[i] == 0:
    cluster0words = cluster0words + np.array_str((np.take(Vectorizer.get_feature_names(), lisst[1])))

   elif K_Means.labels_[i] == 1:
    cluster1words = cluster1words + np.array_str((np.take(Vectorizer.get_feature_names(), lisst[1])))
```

Answer (score -1):

printing y_kmeans and X will tell you which row belongs to which cluster.

```
kmeanModel_bow = KMeans(n_clusters=2)
y_kmeans = kmeanModel_bow.fit_predict(X)
```

Comment: ask is to print the wordcloud for the kmeans cluster. the solution provided does not cater to the problem.